# PayPal Guest Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, guest-checkout

Im setting up a Magento Shop using PayPal for the first time.

Standard / Express PayPal Checkout works perfectly but only if the customer has a PayPal account. There should be a "guest checkout" option wich allows users to pay via Credit Card without creating a PayPal Account.

To activate this there should be a Checkbox inside the PayPal Configuration: "Enable PayPal Guest Checkout" but there isn't.

Im using Magento 1.9.2.2 (Community)

Is there anything I have to set up before this option shows up? Or did PayPal deactivate Guest Checkout to force users to PayPal Plus?

How it should be:

[image: How it should be]

But I don't have this option:

[image: How it is]

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure this is enabled on the PayPal side too. I'm not 100% sure if this option is available to everyone or only certain tiers, but it is found under `Profile > My selling preferences > Website preferences > PayPal Account Optional`.